# Opening a SQL Server .bak file (Not restoring!)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, restore

I have been reading a LOT of google posts and StackOverflow questions about how to restore a database in SQL Server from a .bak file.

But none of them states how to just READ the tables in the database-backup.
(None that I could find anyway?)

I just want to check out some old information which now has been deleted, without actually restoring the full database.
Is this possible?

.

**EDIT:**

I just wanted to post my T-SQL solution to the problem, so others may use it and I can go back and look it up ;)

First I created a new database called `backup_lookup` and took it offline.
After this I could restore my old database `mydb` to the new one, without ever touching my original.

```
USE master
GO
RESTORE DATABASE backup_lookup
 FROM DISK = 'D:\backup\mydb.bak'
WITH REPLACE,
 MOVE 'mydb' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\backup_lookup.mdf',
 MOVE 'mydb_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\backup_lookup_log.ldf'
GO
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From SQL Server 2008 SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), simply:

1. Connect to your database instance (for example, "localhost\sqlexpress")
2. Either:

   - a) Select the database you want to restore to; or, alternatively
   - b) Just create a new, empty database to restore to.
3. Right-click, Tasks, Restore, Database
4. Device, [...], Add, Browse to your .bak file
5. Select the backup.
   Choose "overwrite=Y" under options.
   Restore the database
6. It should say "100% complete", and your database should be on-line.

PS: Again, I emphasize: you can easily do this on a "scratch database" - you do **not** need to overwrite your current database.  But you **do** need to *RESTORE*.

PPS: You can also accomplish the same thing with T-SQL commands, if you wished to script it.

Comment: Ah, so I could just make a temporarily database and restore it into, and afterwards delete it without any effects on my original database? :)

Answer (score 12):

The only workable solution is to **restore** the `.bak` file. The contents and the structure of those files are **not documented** and therefore, there's really no way (other than an awful hack) to get this to work - definitely not worth your time and the effort!

The only tool I'm aware of that can make sense of `.bak` files without restoring them is [Red-Gate SQL Compare Professional](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) (and the accompanying SQL Data Compare) which allow you to compare your database structure against the contents of a `.bak` file. Red-Gate tools are absolutely marvelous - highly recommended and well worth every penny they cost!

And I just checked their web site - it does seem that you can indeed restore a single table from out of a `.bak` file with SQL Compare Pro ! :-)

Answer (score 9):

There is no standard way to do this. You need to use 3rd party tools such as [ApexSQL Restore](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_restore.aspx) or [SQL Virtual Restore](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/). These tools don’t really read the backup file directly. They get SQL Server to “think” of backup files as if these were live databases.

Comment: SQL Virtual Restore support ended on 6th February 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add my TSQL-scripted solution:

First of all; add a new database named `backup_lookup`.
Then just run this script, inserting your own databases' root path and backup filepath

```
USE [master]
GO
RESTORE DATABASE backup_lookup
 FROM DISK = 'C:\backup.bak'
WITH REPLACE,
 MOVE 'Old Database Name' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\backup_lookup.mdf',
 MOVE 'Old Database Name_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\backup_lookup_log.ldf'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible with SQL Server 2008 alone. You're going to need a third-party tool's help.

It will help you make your .bak act like a live database:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/

Comment: Yet another Red-Gate gem! :-)

Comment: I don't quite understand why Microsoft hasn't decided to make this kind of feature available.. It would be good for business if they did..

Comment: You're right about that. I guess I should just speak for the benefit of the consumers! Bundled power!  * fist in the air! *

Comment: Support for redgate's SQL Virtual Restore ended on 6th February 2015 and it is no longer available.