# Creating a SQL Script from a .bak file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-scripts

**Hello,**

How can I create a SQL Script (*.sql) file from a ".bak" file? This is for SQL Server 2005. Can I create a SQL Script with just the SQL Server 2005 Express?

Comment: Your question has already been answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496737/opening-a-sql-server-bak-file-not-restoring

Comment: Restore the database and then script it out just schema, or schema and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above comment from [Tony Hopkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/968969/tony-hopkinson) was the solution.

Comment: How to script it out?Please explain.Thanks